# What is a NaturaW Word™?

Tags: mathematics, knowledge, pattern, word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a NaturaW Word™.
Use the following examples below to find the rule.

| NaturaW Words™ | Not NaturaW Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| ACID | SWEET |
| HIGH | LOW |
| DICE | ROLL |
| CRY | LAUGH |
| DOES | DONE |
| EDGE | SIDE |
| FAX | PHONE |
| BIRDED | BIRDING |
| WEB | LINE |
| BIG | SMALL |

And, if you want to analyze, here is a CSV version:

```
NaturaW Words™,Not NaturaW Words™
ACID,SWEET
HIGH,LOW
DICE,ROLL
CRY,LAUGH
DOES,DONE
EDGE,SIDE
FAX,PHONE
BIRDED,BIRDING
WEB,LINE
BIG,SMALL
```

Hint 1:

> W = 10K

Hint 2:

> [image]

Comment: Is "Birded" a word?

Comment: @Brandon_J p.p. of the verb "bird" :P
https://www.thefreedictionary.com/bird

Comment: Ah. Very nice. I was thinking of birding as a noun and got thrown off.

Comment: I can't stop seeing rot13(oveqfrrq, synk, naq frqtr) in there.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Considering hints:

> Seems like words written as numbers (A=1, B=2, etc.) appears in first 10000 digits of Euler's number (Hint 1).
>  I checked it [here](https://www.boxentriq.com/code-breaking/euler-number)
>  So words as numbers that are there: 1394, 8978, 4935, 31825, 415519, 5475, 6124, 2918454, 2352, 297 (BIRDED is in link as "291845 4", notice space)
>  And that are not there: 19235520, 121523, 18151212, 1212178, 415145, 19945, 16815145, 291849147, 129145, 191311212
>  Hint "log" and Name "natura" means [Natural logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_logarithm) which has base of Euler's number

Comment: You've found it~ :P