# What is a CirKle Word™?

Tags: mathematics, knowledge, pattern, word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a CirKle Word™.
Use the following examples below to find the rule.

| CirKle Words™ | Not CirKle Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| WED | FRI |
| LAB | OFFICE |
| HOT | COLD |
| MIDI | USB |
| CAR | BIKE |
| RED | BLUE |
| ARE | WERE |
| EARED | EARING |
| BAD | GOOD |
| BIG | SMALL |

And, if you want to analyze, here is a CSV version:

```
CirKle Words™,Not CirKle Words™
WED,FRI
LAB,OFFICE 
HOT,COLD 
MIDI,USB 
CAR,BIKE 
RED,BLUE 
ARE,WERE 
EARED,EARING 
BAD,GOOD 
BIG,SMALL
```

Comment: why are all the words so short??

Comment: @OmegaKrypton Check the answer you'll find why :P

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It seems like all CirKle words

> When written as numbers (A=1, B=2, etc.) appear in the first 1000 digits of $\pi$.

Example

> $WED \rightarrow (23,5,4) \rightarrow 2354$ and the digits $2354$ appear in that order in the first 1000 digits of
>  $\pi = $3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510
>          58209749445923078164062862089986280348253421170679
>         82148086513282306647093844609550582231725359408128
>         48111745028410270193852110555964462294895493038196
>          44288109756659334461284756482337867831652712019091
>          45648566923460348610454326648213393607260249141273
>          72458700660631558817488152092096282925409171536436
>          78925903600113305305488204665213841469519415116094
>          33057270365759591953092186117381932611793105118548
>          07446237996274956735188575272489122793818301194912
>          98336733624406566430860213949463952247371907021798
>          60943702770539217176293176752384674818467669405132
>          00056812714526356082778577134275778960917363717872
>          14684409012249534301465495853710507922796892589**235
>
>          4**2019956112129021960864034418159813629774771309960
>          51870721134999999837297804995105973173281609631859
>          50244594553469083026425223082533446850352619311881
>          71010003137838752886587533208381420617177669147303
>          59825349042875546873115956286388235378759375195778
>          18577805321712268066130019278766111959092164201989

Meaning of the name

> $\pi$ is the constant associated with the circle (ratio of circumference to diameter) and $K$ is synonymous with $1000$.

Comment: Uh, how did you find this out?

Comment: @justhalf I developed on a hunch after seeing the answer to [this question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/87117/what-is-a-naturaw-word)

Comment: Ah, and there are more hints there. Makes sense.